# Can't delete file after calling FontFactory.getFont() method

Tags: java, fonts, itext, itextpdf, delete-file

I am using iTextPdf 5.5.3 to create PDF/A documents, I want the user to select custom fonts by uploading the **.ttf** file of the font, and becuase `FontFactory.getFont()` method only takes the font name as a string I have to write the uploaded file to the user's drive (**I KNOW**, I ASKED MY CUSTOMER FOR PERMISSION TO WRITE TO THE DRIVE) and then pass the path of the uploaded file to the `getFont()` method, after everything is finished I want to delete the uploaded files from the drive. Here is my code:

```
File fontFile = new File("d:/temp/testFont.ttf");
try {
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(fontFile);
    outStream.write(the bytes of the uploaded font file);

    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();                          
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


Font font = FontFactory.getFont(fontFile.getAbsolutePath(), BaseFont.CP1250 , BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

fontFile.delete();
```

This code is not working, somehow the `getFont()` method is locking the font file and therefore the file is not being deleted. I tried lots of ways to do this, like: `fontFile.deleteOnExit();` or `FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete("file path");` but nothing is working for me. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going to answer the question mentioned in the title of your post (because it is a secondary). Instead I am going to answer the question in the body (which is the essential question).

You claim that `FontFactory.getFont()` requires a font file on the file system. That is not incorrect. However, that doesn't mean you can't create a font from a `byte[]`.

You are trying to solve your problem by saving a `ttf` on disk (which is forbidden by your customer), but that isn't necessary. In a way, your customer is right: it's not a good idea to save the TTF as a temporary file on disk (which is why I'm ignoring your secondary question).

Take a look at [the following `createFont()` method](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseFont.html#createFont(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20byte[],%20byte[])):

```
public static BaseFont createFont(String name,
        String encoding,
        boolean embedded,
        boolean cached,
        byte[] ttfAfm,
        byte[] pfb)
    throws DocumentException,
        IOException
```

This is how you should interpret the parameters in your case:

- `name` - the name of the font (not the location)
- `encoding` - the encoding to be applied to this font
- `embedded` - `true` if the font is to be embedded in the PDF
- `cached` - probably `false` in your case, as you won't be reusing the font in the JVM
- `ttfAfm` - the bytes of the .ttf file
- `pfb` - in your case, this value will be`null` (it only makes sense in the context of Type1 fonts).

Now you can meet the requirements of your customer and you do not need to introduce a suboptimal workaround.

**Note:** you are using iText 5.5.3 which is available under the AGPL. Please be aware that your customer will need to purchase a commercial license with iText Software as soon as he starts using iText in a web service, in a product,...

Comment: Thank you Mr. Bruno, although I have another question regarding to the encoding of the fonts. How can I know which encoding should I use when create fonts with BaseFont.createFont method?

Comment: Your safest bet is to use Identity-H as this allows you to use UNICODE. A majority of modern fonts support it. If a font doesn't support it, an exception will be thrown. It's up to you to decide whether you refuse such a font (probably the best option) or present the user with the list of available encodings (risking that the user has no clue what you're talking about).